# Find a constant in a binomial expansion

Tags: linear-algebra, binomial-coefficients

Find the constant 'a' in the binomial expansion: $(1-2x)(1+ax)^{10}$ given that the coefficient of $x^6$ is $0$.

I get 9.86, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1-2x)(1+ax)^{10}$

$=$ The coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1+ax)^{10}-2\cdot($ The coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1+ax)^{10})$

Now the $r$ th term $T_{r+1}$ of $(1+ax)^{10}$ is $\binom{10}r(ax)^r$ where $0\le r\le10$

$\implies $The coefficient of $x^6$ in $(1+ax)^{10}$ is $\binom{10}6a^6$

$\implies $The coefficient of $x^5$ in $(1+ax)^{10}$ is $\binom{10}5a^5$

We need $\displaystyle\binom{10}6a^6-2\binom{10}5a^5=0$

$$\implies \frac{10!a^6}{6!4!}=\frac{2\cdot10!a^5}{5!5!}$$

$$\implies a^510!(5!5!a-2\cdot6!4!)=0$$

So, either $a^5=0\implies a=0$

or $\displaystyle a=\frac{2\cdot6!4!}{5!5!}=\frac{12}5$

Comment: I don't understand that second line...

Comment: @missiledragon, we have $1\cdot(1+ax)^{10}-2x(1+ax)^{10}$ right?

Comment: Yeah, but then what?

Comment: @missiledragon, we need $1(?\cdot x^6)-2x(?\cdot x^5),$ right

Comment: Why do we need to find out the coefficient of $x^5$?

Comment: @missiledragon, there is a multiplier $-2x$

Comment: Oh right...
Right now I have $10Ck a^{10-k} x^{10-k} - 2x * 10Ck a^{10-k} x^{10-k}$

What now?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The coefficient of $x^6$ is $\dfrac{10!}{6!\cdot4!}a^6-2\dfrac{10!}{5!\cdot5!}a^5=\dfrac{10!}{6!\cdot5!}a^5\left( 5a - 12 \right)$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(1-2x)(1+ax)^{10}=(1-2x)\sum_{i=0}^{10}\binom{10}{i}(ax)^i=$$
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{10}\binom{10}{i}(ax)^i-2x\sum_{i=0}^{10}\binom{10}{i}(ax)^i$$
from given conditions follow that
$$\binom{10}{6}a^6-2\binom{10}{5}a^5=0$$

$$\binom{10}{6}a=2\binom{10}{5}$$